# Python drop duplicates by conditions

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

**Problem Statement:** Recruiter wants to recruit an aspirant for a particular job with specific skill and City on the basis of first cum serve. For ex if candidate P1 is selected for JOB 'A'then both JOB 'A' and candidate 'P1' should be dropped for next selection.

Below is the sample dataframe

df

```
Job Skill   City    Id  Job_Id
A   Science London  P1  A_P1
A   Science London  P2  A_P2
B   Science London  P1  B_P1
B   Science London  P2  B_P2
C   Science London  P1  C_P1
C   Science London  P2  C_P2
D   Science London  P1  D_P1
D   Science London  P2  D_P2
E   Maths   London  P3  E_P3
E   Maths   London  P4  E_P4
```

Scipt tried :

```
df.drop_duplicates(['Skill', 'City','Id']).drop_duplicates('Job')
```

Output got

```
Job Skill   City    Id  Job_Id
A   Science London  P1  A_P1
E   Maths   London  P3  E_P3
```

Expected output :

```
Job Skill   City    Id  Job_Id
A   Science London  P1  A_P1
B   Science London  P2  B_P2
E   Maths   London  P3  E_P3
```

Since P1 is utlised for A, P2 is still available for B and hence P2 must be selected for B. Since P1 and P2 is utlised for A and B, so they should not be available for C and D.

Comment: Could there be more than 2 candidates for the same job?

Comment: No ! One Job one candidate ! Once selected then both job and candidate will not available for next selection.

Comment: @AB14 I think the question was about more than 2 candidates in the source data.

Comment: @AB14, I meant the input data (not the final result)

Comment: Two or more candidates can be available for the selection but intent is to select the first candidate for that job !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With auxiliary function and `set` object to capture unique candidates (not yet recruited):

```
def f(x, s):
    x = x[~x['Id'].isin(s)].head(1)  # check for valid candidate (not yet hired)
    if not x.empty:
        s.add(x['Id'].values[0])  # add/save recruited candidate
        return x

cands = set()
recruted = (df.groupby(['Job', 'Skill', 'City'], as_index=False)
            .apply(f, s=cands).reset_index(drop=True))
print(recruted)
```

---

```
  Job    Skill    City  Id Job_Id
0   A  Science  London  P1   A_P1
1   B  Science  London  P2   B_P2
2   E    Maths  London  P3   E_P3
```